# Zlib not available in OS X?

Tags: python, macos, zlib

I am trying to install a python library and receive this error after downloading an egg file.

```
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c7-py2.5.egg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    use_setuptools(min_version=min_version)
  File "/Users/tylo/Downloads/Archives/simplejson-2.0.9/ez_setup.py", line 88, in use_setuptools
    import setuptools; setuptools.bootstrap_install_from = egg
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

I did some research and discovered that zlib is built into OS X.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you `import zlib` at a Python prompt?

Comment: I believe I must have multiple Python installations. When I do what you asked in IDLE's python prompt, it works fine. When I do it in my terminal, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 11):

Run `xcode-select --install` to fix installation of Command Line Tools for Xcode working.

Comment: updated xcode and did forget to have the cli tools reinstalled - thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

It's not the zlib *C library* that is missing, but the zlib *Python module*. This is usually caused by compiling Python yourself, and not having the necessary bits (header files, specifically) of zlib available, even when you do have the C library available. Or, sometimes, by the zlib Python module having the wrong permissions; take a look in the directories in `sys.path`, looking for a `zlib.so` or `zlibmodule.so`. If it doesn't exist, the Python installation was built without it, or building it failed. If it does exist, check its permissions (and the directory's permissions.)

Comment: while you are right about the module - recent osx manages file permissions automagically - at least for the bundled components.